# Error in table creation with Airflow in BigQuery - "Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: 'reason': 'accessDenied' "

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, access-denied, drive, google-cloud-composer

i'm trying to create a table in a **BigQuery** dataset through a Directed Acyclic Graph with Google **Cloud Composer.**
This is the Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test-prod.REZ_TEST.ANAGRAPHICS_FINAL` AS
(
WITH 
    COD_ART_NOT_2021 AS (SELECT *
                          FROM `test-prod.PRZ_TEST.ANAGRAPHICS_2020`
                          WHERE CodArt NOT IN (SELECT CodArt
                                               FROM `test-prod.PRZ_TEST.ANAGRAPHICS_2021`
                                               WHERE Ricorsivita IS NOT NULL
                                               ORDER BY CodArt ASC))

SELECT CodArt, BusinessUnit, AnagraficaERP, AnagraficaCGD, Ricorsivita, ServiceType, EBT, 2021 AS Year
FROM `test-prod.PRZ_TEST.ANAGRAPHICS_2021`
WHERE Ricorsivita IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, 2020 AS Year
FROM COD_ART_NOT_2021
);
```

`test-prod.PRZ_TEST.ANAGRAPHICS_2020` and `test-prod.PRZ_TEST.ANAGRAPHICS_2021` are two table created in BigQuery from a **Google Sheet**, therefore they are attached to the Google Sheet.

When i trigger the Airflow DAG this query return an error:

`Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'accessDenied', 'location': 'xyz', 'message': 'Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.'}.`

Is so tricky, I did a lot of steps to try to fix the problem:

1. Add as Editor the service-account of the Composer within the Google Sheet
2. Set a lot of permissons (BigQuery Data Editor, BigQuery Data Owner,BigQuery User, Composer Worker, Editor) to the Composer service account

But still not work..

**WARNING:**
If i run this query in the BigQuery editor the query work, so is probably a problem of permissions.
Someone know the reason??

Comment: What is the IAM policy on the BigQuery tables created from the Google Sheet?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls#bq

Comment: @OluwafemiSule i don't know how to check the IAM policy of the BigQuery Table

Comment: Table creation permissions are not (yet) the problem. You need to get Drive credentials. Try this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#enable-google-drive